# Keep adding first two numbers

Tags: java

I wrote a Fibonacci class that contains a fillFibonacciArray method. This method should take a single parameter, an array. It will use the first two elements of the array as the first two numbers of a Fibonacci sequence and fill the rest of the array with the rest of the sequence.My fillFibonacciArray method should not print or return anything it merely modifies the array passed as a parameter. I do not know if I did it correct. Could anyone please check? If there is anything wrong please correct me ^^ Thank you.!

```
public class Fibonacci
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] fibNumbers = fillFibonacciArray(9);
        fillFibonacciArray(fibNumbers);
    }

    private static void fillFibonacciArray(int[] fibNumbers)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fibNumbers.length; i++)
        {

            System.out.print(fibNumbers[i]+" ");

        }
    }

    private static int[] fillFibonacciArray(int maxIndex)
    {
        int[] fibNumbers = new int[maxIndex];

        if (maxIndex > 0)
        {
            fibNumbers[0] = 1;
            if (maxIndex > 1)
            {
                fibNumbers[1] = 1;

                for (int i = 2; i < fibNumbers.length; i++)
                {
                    fibNumbers[i] = fibNumbers[i-2] + fibNumbers[i-1];
                }
            }
        }
        return fibNumbers;
    }
}
```

Output:
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem?  The output looks good to me.

Comment: You seem to be getting the correct sequence in the output... however your method doesn't follow your own instructions: "This method should take **a single parameter, an array**" and "My fillFibonacciArray method should **not print or return anything**".

Comment: "It will use the first two elements of the array as the first two numbers of a Fibonacci sequence and fill the rest of the array with the rest of the sequence." - That's not quite what you've done, right?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure it out. How can I do it?

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't really have two different methods, that do two completely different things, but have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

This fulfills all the stated requirements:

```
public class Fibonacci {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] fibNumbers = new int[20];
        fibNumbers[0] = fibNumbers[1] = 1;

        fillFibonacciArray(fibNumbers);

        for (int i = 0; i < fibNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(fibNumbers[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    private static void fillFibonacciArray(int[] fibNumbers) {
        final int length = fibNumbers.length;

        if (length < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input array must have a least 2 elements.");
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < length; i++) {
            fibNumbers[i] = fibNumbers[i - 2] + fibNumbers[i - 1];
        }

    }

}
```

The output of main() is:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765
```

Answer (score 0):

change this       if (maxIndex > 1)
by
if (maxIndex > 2) 
or will happen a error in your code for because of i-2 if your pass array size =2,1 or 0

Comment: No it won't.  The code is fine as it is.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, the code is perfect, sorry except by the fact commented by @mellamokb

Answer (score 0):

imho, according to OP's requirement, it should be like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonacci
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter first two elements> ");
        int first = s.nextInt();
        int second = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("define array size> ");
        int size = s.nextInt();

        if(size > 2){
            int[] fibNumbers = new int[size];
            fibNumbers[0] = first;
            fibNumbers[1] = second;
            fillFibonacciArray(fibNumbers);
        }
    }

    private static void fillFibonacciArray(int[] fibNumbers)
    {
        int maxIndex = fibNumbers.length;

         for (int i = 2; i < fibNumbers.length; i++)
         {
             fibNumbers[i] = fibNumbers[i-2] + fibNumbers[i-1];
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite.  On calling the method, the first two elements should be already populated.

Comment: opps, good point, I forgot to use the input.. ah..

Comment: Right, now that you've set `fibNumbers[0]` and `fibNumbers[1]` before calling `fillFibonacciArray`, there's no point in your checks on `maxIndex` any more.  If the requested size is less than 2, then your program has already crashed at this point.